# Uploading training data to amazon p2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to upload a folder of training images to an Amazon p2 instance?

Comment: Where is the data currently located?

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon EC2 instance is a virtual machine just like any other computer. The fact that it is running on Amazon EC2 makes no difference.

It is often easier to "pull" data onto a computer, rather than "pushing" data onto it. Therefore, I would recommend logging into the instance, then downloading the data.

If the data is on your own computer, this could be difficult to access from the Internet, so I would recommend:

- Copy the data from your computer to an Amazon S3 bucket
- From the EC2 instance, download the data from Amazon S3

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a `aws s3 sync` command that can easily copy folders of data to/from Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How should I download data from the EC2 instance then?

Comment: It's just another computer. How would you "download" data from a computer on the Internet? It would either need to be running as a web server, or you would need to be able to login to the machine and send data somewhere (or use scp). Again, it's probably easier to login to the instance and copy the data to S3 as an intermediary, since computers (eg your laptop) by default don't serve data unless they are running a web server, FTP server, etc. If the EC2 instance is a Windows computer, you could also install file-sharing software like DropBox or Google Drive.